# A question about divisor function and primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\sigma_1(n)$ denotes the divisor function which sums the divisors of a natural number $n > 1$.
We calculate the remainder of the division of $\sigma(n+\sigma(n+1+\sigma(n+2)))$ by $n+1$. $r$ is the remainder. 
We focus on the case $r = 6$.
We prove easily that $r = 6$ when $n+2$ and $4n+9$ are prime.
However it exists other cases where $r = 6$, for example with $n = 17$ or $n = 6001$ or $n = 332861$.
The common point between these examples is that $\sigma(n+\sigma(n+1+\sigma(n+2)))-1 = 5k$ ($k$ is an integer $> 1$).

I was wondering if :

1. my observations are correct
2. we can prove that $\sigma(n+\sigma(n+1+\sigma(n+2)))-1 = 5k$ when $r = 6$ and when $4n+9$ is not prime.

I failed to prove the second point.

Thanks.

Comment: How far did you check the second conjecture ?

Comment: I checked the conjecture for $n = 10k+1$ ($k$ an integer) from $1$ to $2^{19}$.

Comment: We can reformulate the conjecture as following. Let $p=n+2$. Let $p$ be a prime number such that $4p+1$ is not prime. We suppose $\sigma(4p+1) \equiv 6 \mod (p-1)$ Demonstrate that $\sigma(4p+1) \equiv 1 \mod 5$